# How to change the value of a line in specific column in a txt file Python?

Tags: python

I have a text file with 1 column of different values (floating and integer) and I would like to change a value according to its line. my code is as follows: but I did it knowing what value I should replace, how to do it according to the line?

```
with open('table1.txt', 'r+') as file:
    text = file.read()
    i = text.index('3.6') # 3.6 = old value
    file.seek(0)
    file.write(text[:i] + '7.84' + text[i + len('3.6'):]) # 7.84 = new value
```

Secondly, how can I choose a row when there are several columns in my file? For example, column 2 row 1? ? thanx

Comment: This is not a python question. Please move this question to https://unix.stackexchange.com/ or similar sites

Comment: so you are asking how to use `sed` or how to process your txt file with python?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, I was wrong, I just corrected now is my good question

Comment: you can use file.readline() or use iterator on file object to read line by line and use var count to count line no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if columns in your file are splited by space:

```
def change_value(column, row, new_value):
    lines = []
    with open('table1.txt', 'r+') as file:
        for line in file:
            lines.append(line.rstrip().split())

        lines[row - 1][column - 1] = str(new_value)
        file.seek(0)
        for line in lines:
            line[-1] += "\n"    # or "\r\n" on windows
            file.write(' '.join(line))


change_value(2, 1, 7.84)
```

Comment: Thank you very much it works very well :D !  But how to manage the spaces in file.write()? if for example I want after 3 written values it to return to the line. so that I can find the initial columns.

Comment: I'am not complitly understand your question. Pleas tell litle more.
in that example, you can get any line in `lines` list. line contain values of columns 

just do `lines[index_of_line_you_want][index_of_column_you_want]`.
indexes is numirated from 0, that why in example I get it like `[index - 1]`
do all manipulations with data you want  after file is readed and before it writen.

Comment: how to return to the line all 3 values? because here the code works well but modifies the text file by writing all the values in succession. example :     change_value(2, 1, 7.84) --> 1.007825 7.84 0.5 0.95 4.002603 0 0.5 0.05 ... We no longer see the columns in the file

Comment: now your columns are separated by spaces.
betwin the quotes in `' '.join(line)` you can set a separator of columns. it may be two spaces or any you want. The symbol `\t` will set space betwin column aqual the one tab, if you want two - set `\t\t`and so on...
if you will set non-spaced symbol like `-` or other, you shoud set same in previos ...`.split("your_separator_here")` method to corect read and divide values from line. By defalt it seted to space.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes thank you so much !  but a other little problem, when I put row > 1 I have directly  :  
`change_value(2, 2, 7.84)
  File "run.py", line 7, in change_value
    lines[row - 1][column - 1] = str(new_value)
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: I found my mistake! everything is working very well now! thank you very much :D   (it was : `lines.append(line.rstrip().split()[0:4])` to create 4 columns

Comment: @F.Moab Ok. Than accept my answer, please. Thank you.